# JDK 21 Windows not compatible to Netbeans 19 installer

Tags: java, netbeans

I downloaded JDK 21 in windows and follow instructions from youtube but when I tried to install netbeans this error message shows **The specified JDK folder contains JDK version "2513.0.0.0.0", while the maximum is "500.0.0.0.0".**

The JDK file should automatically show in the browse instead of having a warning

Comment: The answers correctly point out that NetBeans 19 does not formally support JDK 21, but if you really want to use it just avoid using the Installer to install NetBeans. Instead, [simply download and unzip](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb19/) **netbeans-19-bin.zip** to install NetBeans 19. I'm using it with JDK 21 and it _seems_ fine, but don't be too surprised if you encounter problems.

Answer (score 3):

## RTFM

Read the fine manual.

[The documentation](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb19/) clearly states that NetBeans 19 runs on specific versions of Java. Java 21 is not one.

> The Apache NetBeans 19 binary releases require JDK 11+, and officially support running on JDK 11, 17 and 20.

Therefore, NetBeans 19 *might* run on Java 21, or might not.

If you encounter problems on Java 21:

- Investigate if any available early-access versions of future NetBeans support Java 21.
- Check their issue-tracking system to find any tickets on adding support for Java 21.

Answer (score 1):

JDK21 does not support Netbeans 19 yet.
Use JDK20 for now: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk20-archive-downloads.html

Comment: I think you meant to write "_Netbeans 19 does not support JDK21 yet_".

Comment: By the way, don't make a confusion between Java, Oracle Java and OpenJDK. Using Java doesn't imply to use Oracle Java.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have found.

If you have a project that is Java 17 and you wish to switch it to Java 21 in NetBeans, you will need to do two things; make sure javac points to javac version 21 (javac -version) and select the "Run Compilation in External VM" in the Project Properties Build|Compiling.

I have OpenJDK 21.0.1 set up as the default java/javac/javadoc/javap (I am using Linux, so setting this up is easy using symbolic links) and it all works fine.